# Blender can only set One shader nodes (Material) for One UDIM tile?

Tags: texturing, uv

Hi all I usually manually set UDIM tiles UV in edit mode. so not care much about blender new UDIM way. What I do not understand clear is..

Now I have 2 material-slots which assgined for One UV tiles.
eg 1001 tile include 2 different material slot (Material)  for Eye and Eyelash.
So Eye and Eyelash use different shader nodes, but texture is same.

1002 UV tile include 2 different material slot and shader groups for nail and hand .
I only need one texture for 1002 (diffuse normal, roughness) but I use different shader group.

If I do not set Blender UDIM , it work without problem. (I only arrange UV tiles as UDIM)

And I know blender can set only one material for multiple UV tiles as UDIM, then I can use different textures for each UDIM tile. (but use one material)

but Can I set 1 UDIM texture set <> 1001 UV tile , but separate as material (eye and eyelush) with use blender UDIM texture?

Or if I hope to devide 2 material for one UDIM tile, I should not set Blender UDIM texture?